Why NPM recommend @types packages as --save dependencies?
NPM always recommand add @types as --save dependencies in their README.md file , like @types/node, @types/express, @types/bun, which shouldn't be like this. Because I always add these as --save-dev, and they should be treated like this. This really confuses me.



As @DanielRosenwasser mentioned:

Using --save-dev is fine when you're writing a simple application, and it won't be used as a library. The problem comes along when you might have dependencies. If you stored your type declarations in your devDependencies, your consumers would not automatically get your type declarations. They'd then have to manually add your declaration file dependencies as their devDependencies.


Given that breaking consumers is a worse problem than slightly-larger packages, we've made --save the default in our documentation.

And, @blakeembrey said:

The short answer would be for module authors - if, as an author, you want to publish your TypeScript package to NPM and the dependencies are in the development section, no one will be able to install it and use it without having to manually install your types dev dependencies. By using dependencies, they will be installed along with the package and consumers can use your NPM package without additional configuration. The definitions should follow however you installed the module.

See Why --save instead of --save-dev?
So I think, by default, npm install @types/express --save command is for authors of packages such as express, not users who use these packages.
For authors of packages, you should use npm i @types/<PACKAGE_NAME> --save
For users of packages, you should use npm i @types/<PACKAGE_NAME> --save-dev
